# Moxios - TypeError: Cannot read property 'adapter' of undefined

Tags: testing, axios, moxios

Trying to test `axios` calls and trying the `moxios` package.

`"axios": "^0.16.2",`
`"moxios": "^0.4.0",`

Found here: https://github.com/axios/moxios

Following there example, but my test errors out on the `moxios.install()` line:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import moxios from 'moxios'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import { equal } from 'assert'

describe('mocking axios requests', function () {

  describe('across entire suite', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
      // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
      moxios.install()
    })
```

### My actual test

```
import axios from 'axios';
import moxios from 'moxios';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { equal } from 'assert';

const akamaiData = {
  name: 'akamai'
};

describe('mocking axios requests', () => {
  describe('across entire suite', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
      moxios.install();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
      moxios.uninstall();
    });

    it('should stub requests', (done) => {
      moxios.stubRequest('/akamai', {
        status: 200,
        response: {
          name: 'akamai'
        }
      });

      // const onFulfilled = sinon.spy();
      // axios.get('/akamai').then(onFulfilled);
      //
      // moxios.wait(() => {
      //   equal(onFulfilled.getCall(0).args[0], akamaiData);
      //   done();
      // });
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

I did find this closed issue here, however the fix "passing `axios` into the `moxios.install(axios)` function did not work"

https://github.com/axios/moxios/issues/15

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Turns out I did not need `moxios`, in my test I did not want to make an actual API call... just needed to make sure that function was called. Fixed it with a test function.

```
import { makeRequest } from 'utils/services';
import { getImages } from './akamai';

global.console = { error: jest.fn() };

jest.mock('utils/services', () => ({
  makeRequest: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { foo: 'bar' } }))
}));

describe('Akamai getImages', () => {
  it('should make a request when we get images', () => {
    getImages();
    expect(makeRequest).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/akamai', 'GET');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem. It turned out I had an `axios.js` file in my `__mocks__` folder (leftover from a different attempt at mocking axios). That mock file took over the actual axios code -- but moxios needs the *real* axios code to function properly. When I removed the `axios.js` file from the `__mocks__` folder, moxios worked as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was about ES module interop. Try one of the two workarounds:

- Try change `import moxios from 'moxios'` to `import * as moxios from 'moxios'`.
- Set `esModuleInterop` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.